# Ryugu can not be "geo"-synchronized or stationarized?

Tags: classical-mechanics

With the known data of Ryugu asteroid, is therefore no way to be geosynchronized by any probe? The normal formula provides result non-physical. I explain myself...
With real data (at least, with known data), I get no sense of
$$R_\text{Ryugu-stationary}=\sqrt[3]{ \frac{G M_\text{Ryugu}T^2}{4\pi^2}}$$
where T is the rotation period of Ryugu, about 7,6 h.

The mean radius of the Ryugu asteroid, about 850 m, is bigger than the radius of the "geo"-synchronized orbit, about 820m, since $R=radius+height$ is smaller than the "mean" radius of Ryugu, by a few tens of km.

So, the height of the Ryugu-stationary probe would be negative...What is meaningless, since it is solid...

Comment: Can you expand on why you "get no sense of" the value you compute?

Comment: That means that an object on the equator is moving faster than orbital speed.

Comment: The mean diameter (not radius) of 162173 Ryugu is 850 m (not 850 km).

Comment: Typos. Thanks for saying. Anyway, put mass and period into numbers. I got 820 meters, after substracting about 850 meters, I get negative height, but it is meaningless...Unless, the limit of validation of the formula is mathematical. After all, we DO in fact define a mean radius for Jupiter or gas giants, even when no "solid" surface exist there...Similarly,...So, even if you try to calculate, e.g., the velocity to manage a body orbit Earth on its surface from math, it can not be done in practice. I think this is similar to Ryugu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cute trick you can use to see that you've made a mistake, but I'll leave it to you to trace through your arithmetic to find where your mistake is.

It turns out that the orbital period for a "low" orbit, as defined below, depends only on the *density* of the primary.  You have the correct expression for the relation between semimajor axis $R$, period $T$, and primary mass $M$ for a low-mass object in a circular orbit.  Turn it around and solve for the period,

$$
T^2 = (2\pi)^2 \frac{R^3}{GM} \propto \frac{1}{G\rho},
$$

where $\rho \propto M/R^3$ describes the density $\rho$ if the semimajor axis $R$ is not very different from the radius of the primary.

You may be aware that Earth is made of rock and metal, with a mean density of about $5.5\,\rm g/cm^3$, and that satellites in low-Earth orbit have a period of about 90 minutes.  That means that any rock/metal object will also have surface-skimming orbits of about ninety minutes.  Even a super-low-density object like Saturn, with $\rho = 0.6\rm\,g/cm^3$, has surface-skimming (cloudtop-skimming?) orbits that are only about a factor of $\sqrt{5.5 / 0.6} \approx 3$ different from the periods of low-Earth orbits --- about 4.2 hours.

Since Ryugu [has a density](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/364/6437/268) of about $1.1\rm\,g/cm^3$, its surface-skimming orbits are quicker than its seven-hour rotational period; therefore, "geo"-stationary orbits exist at some altitude.

Comment: I don't see the failure yet...I will think on this yesterday in my free day. Thank you for noting.

Comment: I found your error when I tried using your data to compute the asteroid's density --- which is why I linked to a primary source for that information.

Comment: Ah!!!! Typical...I put the diameter as size...Instead of radius...Brilliant!!!!!!